# Custom Annotation Callout Crash -- Help?

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkannotationview

I've successfully added a custom UILabel to an annotation callout, but am failing at making the UILabel display the annotation.title. The app builds fine, but crashes once I tap an annotation. It crashes with SIGABRT at the first line in the code below.

Note: I'm using the code from [Asynchrony Solutions](http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/).

My code is below, thanks!

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
        if (self.calloutAnnotation == nil) {
            self.calloutAnnotation = [[CalloutMapAnnotation alloc] initWithLatitude:view.annotation.coordinate.latitude
                                                                       andLongitude:view.annotation.coordinate.longitude];
        } else {
            self.calloutAnnotation.latitude = view.annotation.coordinate.latitude;
            self.calloutAnnotation.longitude = view.annotation.coordinate.longitude;
        }
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:self.calloutAnnotation];
        self.selectedAnnotationView = view;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    if (self.calloutAnnotation && 
        view.annotation == self.customAnnotation && 
        !((BasicMapAnnotationView *)view).preventSelectionChange) {
        [self.mapView removeAnnotation: self.calloutAnnotation];
    }
}
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    NSLog(@"Ann Title: %@", annotation.title);
    theAnnTitle = annotation.title;
    NSLog(@"Ann Title 2: %@", theAnnTitle);

    if (annotation == self.calloutAnnotation) {
        CalloutMapAnnotationView *calloutMapAnnotationView = (CalloutMapAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CalloutAnnotation"];
        if (!calloutMapAnnotationView) {
            calloutMapAnnotationView = [[[AccessorizedCalloutMapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                                                             reuseIdentifier:@"CalloutAnnotation"] autorelease];
            calloutMapAnnotationView.contentHeight = 70.0f;

            UILabel *annTitle = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
            annTitle.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50);
            annTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            annTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            annTitle.text = theAnnTitle;
            //NSLog(@"Ann Title 3: %@", theAnnTitle);

            [calloutMapAnnotationView.contentView addSubview:annTitle];
        }
        calloutMapAnnotationView.parentAnnotationView = self.selectedAnnotationView;
        calloutMapAnnotationView.mapView = self.mapView;
        return calloutMapAnnotationView;
    } else if (annotation == self.customAnnotation) {
        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[BasicMapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                                                               reuseIdentifier:@"CustomAnnotation"] autorelease];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
        annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        return annotationView;
    } else if (annotation == self.normalAnnotation) {
        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[BasicMapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                                                               reuseIdentifier:@"NormalAnnotation"] autorelease];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
        annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        return annotationView;
    } else {
        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[BasicMapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                                                               reuseIdentifier:@"CustomAnnotation"] autorelease];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
        annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        return annotationView;

    }
    return nil;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    self.customAnnotation = [[[BasicMapAnnotation alloc] initWithLatitude:38.6335 andLongitude:-90.2045] autorelease];
    self.customAnnotation.title = @"I AM ANGRYY!";
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:self.customAnnotation];

    self.normalAnnotation = [[[BasicMapAnnotation alloc] initWithLatitude:38 andLongitude:-90.2045] autorelease];
    self.normalAnnotation.title = @"I AM HAPPY";
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:self.normalAnnotation];

    BasicMapAnnotation *behindCalloutAnnotation = [[[BasicMapAnnotation alloc] initWithLatitude:38.9 andLongitude:-89.5] autorelease];
    behindCalloutAnnotation.title = @"I Am Selected.";
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:behindCalloutAnnotation];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = {38.315, -90.2045};
    [self.mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, 
                                                   MKCoordinateSpanMake(1, 1))];
}
```

Crash Logs:

```
2011-09-08 12:07:05.735 CustomMapAnnotationExample[24648:e903] -[CalloutMapAnnotation title]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc256a00
2011-09-08 12:07:05.736 CustomMapAnnotationExample[24648:e903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CalloutMapAnnotation title]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc256a00'
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

Comment: What class is CalloutMapAnnotation? Does it have a "title" property?  That's where the problem is but you haven't shown it's interface.

Comment: The CalloutMapAnnotation is just a view for the actual callout... I added a "tile" property and it no longer crashes.. BUT, it returns an annotation.title of `null` ... how can I connect the customAnnotation.title to the calloutAnnotation.title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you see if happening on the very first line of code in your method where you print `annotation.title`. (The error says: the annotation object does not understand the `title` method)

So you will need to show some more code. Specifically the code where you create and add those annotations and maybe also the implementation of your `MKAnnotation`

The above method is not the problem.

Comment: I updated my answer... just FYI everything worked perfectly until I added the first three lines in `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation;`

Answer (score 0):

`title` is an optional property for the MKAnnotation protocol. Not every annotation will have that property, so you can't set or use that property until you're certain that the property is available. Even if an annotation has that property, the standard definition isn't read/write it's readonly.

Options:

1. Move any references to that property into an if/then block, once you've tested the annotation's class and therefore know that the property is read/write available.
2. Alternatively, use `if ([annotation respondsToSelector:@selector(setTitle:)])` to check for read/write.